# Clion doesn't highlight errors

Tags: highlight, clion

Using Clion 2020.1.2 on Manjaro

As the title implies the IDE doesn't underline/highlight errors in my editor while writing.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    foo;
    return 0;
}
```

In this case `foo;` is not highlighted as an error in the editor, even if undeclared. It's only recognized by the compiler at compile time.
Other cases include: assigning wrong type to a function's parameter, forgetting semicolons, syntax errors in general.

Power saving mode is already disabled.

Comment: This question should be addressed to CLion [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP) rather here.

Comment: Code highlighting in CLion works only if the file has been added into the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Are you sure that your project is properly configured?